# What is the best Wiki Gem for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, wiki

I'm looking for a Wiki Gem for RoR that has:

- basic Wiki features (obviously),
- a history feature on all entries,
- uses MySQL (no SQLite),
- optionally, instead of using articles, we would like to define some fields to use, in a template…

If I had to cite an example of a website using similar kind of features, it would be CrunchBase. It is a wiki-like system, with predefined fields.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Wiki gem for Rails, per-se. What you do have are a few gems that will facilitate developing a Wiki much like what you're looking for here.

For versioning, I would recommend [vestal_versions](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions), and for rendering Markdown, I would recommend [BlueCloth](http://deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth). Both of these gems have been out for a while, and are quite mature and well tested.

vestal_versions is also DB agnostic, as it piggybacks on ActiveRecord features, so it will work in whatever RDBMS you throw it at.

Comment: Thank you very much **changelog**. This was very useful and we are implementing your suggestions now.